# Channel-wise Google adsense information

Tags: php, adsense, adsense-api

I am using adsense Management API and followed everything there to generate a demo report as it is described in the example on their site. 
The information I am currently fetching uses this information :

```
    $startDate = '2012-03-01';
    $endDate = '2012-04-18';
    $optParams = array(
      'filter' => array(
        'AD_CLIENT_ID==' . $adClientId
      ),
      'metric' => array(                    
        'CLICKS', 'PAGE_VIEWS','COST_PER_CLICK','EARNINGS'                  
      ),
      'dimension' => array('DATE'),
      'sort' => 'DATE'
    );
```

What I have to ask is is it possible to arrange this data according to the channels So that I get channel-wise information on EARNING, COST_PER_CLICK and PAGE_VIEWS. And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about custom channels, all you have to do is add one of the following to your list of dimensions, depending on what you prefer:

- CUSTOM_CHANNEL_NAME
- CUSTOM_CHANNEL_ID
- CUSTOM_CHANNEL_CODE

You can think of dimensions as groups, that is, what you're organising your data by.

You can check [this blog post](http://adsenseapi.blogspot.com/2011/11/adsense-management-api-diving-into.html) for some more info.